# WordPress working only with permissions as 777

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, apache, permissions

I have installed WordPress on my VPS server. (Centos, Linux, apache). But after installing, WordPress is not able to create files.

If I set the permissions for WordPress directory and its subfolders as 777 everything is working fine. But I know setting 777 is very dangerous.

What permissions should I set? or how can I fix this?

I used this command to set permissions

```
chmod 777 wordpress_folder -R
```

Comment: better do 755 on directories and 644 on files.

Comment: I have already tried setting 755 using the above command. Do I have to set permissions for files separately?

Comment: yes, in general you don't need to write into the files, just into the folders.

Answer (score 2):

In you wordpress directory, run the following commands:

`find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;`

`find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;`

Whereas the first command will modify all your directories to 775 and the second command will modify all your files to 664. This should do the trick.

Comment: its not working. Even after doing that i am unable to upload files

Answer (score 0):

It is very dangerous indeed to use 777. The last digit means that anybody is allowed to read, write and execute your files.

The proper way to do it is to do a `chown -R apache:apache wordpress_folder` and then make sure that none of the files have 777.

This way the files will be owned by the user which runs the web server and so the webserver will be allowed to write stuff.

Comment: so what permission should i set?

Answer (score 0):

You don't specified your PHP Handler(I guess is mod_php or CGI) because this handlers do not run files as owner.

I had this problems few years ago with mod_php & CGI as handlers with: WordPress and SMF forum.

I recommend you to use suPHP or FastCGI as handler(you are on VPS and this handlers are known as 'Low Memory Usage') and avoid problems with folder permissions with some CMS.

- suPHP & FastCGI - Run as file owner, so no folder permission problems with WordPress.
- with suPHP or FastCGI when you must upload pictures in your WordPress website isn't required ftp login for upload(and this is a big + for you and your editors/users).

Comment: If i use php 7, will it increase the speed and reduce ram usage?

Comment: PHP 7 (rebuild from scratch) is known for 2x faster performance and 50% better memory consumption, this following to serve more concurrent users without adding any hardware.
But from my experience everything what is new have a lot of incompatibilities with other apps and a lot of bugs too. When big players like cPanel, Plesk, Direct Admin or ISPManager made the change I made the change too. In business your 1st choice is to test others new developments(time for bugs and incompatibilities means money). 
So I do not tested yet PHP 7.

Comment: Ok. I have a few wordpress websites. If i upgrade my php to php 7, will those websites work?

Comment: I can not answer to this question exactly. But remember that almost plugin developers test their plugins to work till PHP 5.6.
Check your plugins compatibility, ask at WP support forum and test with 1 website(do a backup first) and after few days, a week investigate if everything works OK or not.

Answer (score 0):

I normaly login in via SSH and than run the following comands
find public_html/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +
find public_html/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +
and all sorted.